# How can I create an interface that is a specialization of another interface?

Tags: typescript

Simply, I want to have

```
interface Shape {
  sides: number
  color: string
}

interface Square extends Shape {
  sides: number = 4
}
```

But this isn't possible because I can't assign a value to a member. In other languages, I might create a property to achieve this, like:

```
interface Square extends Shape {
  sides: number { get { return 4 } }
}
```

But I don't think such a construct exists in typescript. The use case is pretty reasonable; is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you want a `class` instead of an `interface` here? As soon as you have particular specific _data_, you have an _specific implementation_ , you don't have an _interface_ anymore (which is more about _behavior_)

Comment: It would work, but then I need to implement default values for all the members in `Shape`, and would need to do this for every 'specialization' I create (Triangle, Rectangle, etc), which isn't fun to maintain.

Comment: You can use an abstract class for this, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have *data*, you should use a *class* instead of an *interface*.

But you still want to have some kind of vague type, and no actual implementation for the rest of the interface.

To me, this is a usecase for an *abstract class*. You can just mark as abstract what you don't want to implement.

Example here :

```
interface Shape {
  readonly sides: number;
  color: string;
}

abstract class Triangle implements Shape {
  get sides() { return 3 };
  abstract color: string; // let this to be implemented by subclasses.
}
```

Also, in the example above, you can see that you can implement an interface property as a "getter" only, see the [discussion on github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3745).

In this case, I also added `readonly` in the interface to make it clear that this should not change (I guess that was what you intended, let me know if this wasn't the case).

You still have to add a line for each "unimplemented" `Shape` member, but with this class hierarchy I think it's a price to pay.

To avoid having to explicitly mark each missing interface member as `abstract` you could also separate the interfaces:

```
interface Shape {
  readonly sides: number;
}

interface Colored {
  color: string;
}

interface ColoredShape extends Shape, Colored {}

abstract class Rectangle implements Shape {
  sides: number = 4
}

class RedRectangle extends Rectangle implements ColoredShape
{
  get color() { return "red" };
}

class FreeColorRectangle extends Rectangle implements ColoredShape
{
  color: string = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Plain JavaScript objects**

```
interface Shape {
  sides: number
  color: string
}

interface Square extends Shape {
  sides: 4
}

const square: Square = {
  color: 'red',
  sides: 4,
}
```

**JavaScript classes**

```
abstract class Shape {
  sides: number
  color: string

  constructor(sides: number, color: string) {
    this.sides = sides;
    this.color = color;
  }
}

class Square extends Shape {
  constructor(color: string) {
    super(4, color);
  }
}

const square = new Square('red');
```